# How to import COM4j as Eclipse Plugin?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, com4j

I am following the guide shown in https://molteni.wordpress.com/2012/10/16/connect-hp-quality-center-with-java-using-com4j-tutorial/ to generate resources of COM4J.

This is how the COM4J folder looks like

[image]

I tried to create an Eclipse plugin based on it and show as below

[image]

However when I added the plugin as one of the dependencies of my application I am unable to import the file.

I get the following error when I tried to search it through "Open Type" in Eclipse as follow

[image]

What steps am I missing here ?

Answer (score 2):

Usually it is done like this: in Eclipse go to File ->
New -> Plugin Development -> Plugin From Existing Jar Files

[image]

Though it might not help in this case: please see this issue: https://java.net/jira/browse/COM4J-57

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have not specified which classes are exported by the plugin.

Open the MANIFEST.MF editor for the plugin and select the Runtime tab. In the 'Exported Packages' section click Add and select all the packages which should be available to other plugins.

Comment: the `com` folder contains the Java files. In the `Exported Package` I don't see the `com` folder. All I see is the `com4` which have been listed there. I am not able to add the `com` folder through here. What should I do ?

Comment: Having a quick look at the download I don't immediately see any 'com' packages. You are going to have to examine this code in more detail.